# No doctype in an include with html/php

Tags: php, html, include, doctype

I have a PHP include that contains both HTML and PHP code and is included on another page that already has the `<!doctype html>` tag. The HTML validator (w3.org) tells me it has an error when validating the include, because my include file doesn't contain this tag, but since the include is used on pages where doctype is declared, is it really necessary to declare it in the include?

Example:

```
include.php

<div>
<p> Hello  


<?php
echo "world!";
?></p> </div>
```

---

```
index.php

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
include ("include.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error: The document type could not be determined, because the document
>   had no correct DOCTYPE declaration. (include.php)

Comment: You get this error when you call index.php ?

Comment: no, there should be no need to add a doctype declaration within the included file

Comment: No, when I validate include.php I get the decleration error I quoted.

Comment: Are you using HTML5 or 4?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith HTML5

Comment: @Querty I posted your answer for you, and yes it is that easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to validate `include.php` as if it was an HTML document. It isn't, it is a fragment of HTML (and shouldn't have a Doctype declaration of its own).

If you want to validate it it independently of the pages that include it, create a minimal wrapper HTML document and include it in that, then validate the wrapper document.